# SQL - Recurring Calendar Events with Exceptions

Tags: sql, database-design, calendar, schedule

I'm looking for some advice on the best practice for a calendar using recurring events.

Lets say I have a table 'event' with the fields

```
id 
info
```

and another table 'event_meta'
with the fields

```
id
event_id
start_date
end_date
interval
```

I can create a recurring event as follows

event:

```
id | info
---------------
 1 | some info
```

event_meta

```
id | event_Id | start_date | end_date | interval |
--------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------
 1 |     1    | 2020-01-01 |2020-01-30|     7    |
--------------------------------------------------
 1 |     1    | 2020-01-03 |2020-01-30|     7    |
--------------------------------------------------
 1 |     1    | 2020-01-05 |2020-01-30|     7    |
--------------------------------------------------
```

That repeats every wednesday, friday and sunday till the end of the month.

using this query:

```
SELECT * from event_meta
outer join event on event.id = event_meta.id
where (start_date - <todays date>) % interval = 0
and start_date <= <todays date>
and end_date >= <todays date>
```

I can fetch all events for that particular day.

This system breaks when I need to provide exceptions for certain events. For instance if I want to reschedule one instance of an events in a pattern but leave the others unchanged or if I want to update the pattern of events while not shifting the events that should have already occurred.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to implement this in this model or on a different model that would account for this?

Comment: You need some examples of "exceptions".  It is unclear what you mean by that.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have done:

I created an event table like this:

```
| event_id | event_title | start_date | end_date | start_time | end_time | one_time_event | day_sunday | day_monday | day_tuesday | day_wednesday | day_thursday | day_friday | day_saturday | week_month | day_of_month | month_of_year | status | parent_event_id |
|----------|-------------|------------|----------|------------|----------|----------------|------------|------------|-------------|---------------|--------------|------------|--------------|------------|--------------|---------------|--------|-----------------|
| PK       |             |            |          |            |          | bool           | bool       | bool       | bool        | bool          | bool         | bool       | bool         |            |              |               | bool   | FK_TO_event_id  |
```

You can get all the events in date range with this.

```
DECLARE @startDate DATE = '2020-09-01';
DECLARE @endDate DATE = '2020-10-15';

WITH    AllDays AS
           ( SELECT   @startDate AS [Date]
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   DATEADD(DAY, 1, [Date])
               FROM     AllDays
               WHERE    [Date] < @endDate )
SELECT "FULL".Date + CAST(dbo.EventSlots.start_time AS smalldatetime) "DateTime", dbo.EventSlots.* FROM 
    (SELECT [Date], [event_id]
    FROM   AllDays 
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[EventSlots] 
    ON 
    ([dbo].[EventSlots].one_time_event=0 
        AND [dbo].[EventSlots].start_date<=AllDays.Date AND [dbo].[EventSlots].end_date>=AllDays.Date
        AND ( ([dbo].[EventSlots].day_sunday=1 and DATEPART(WEEKDAY, AllDays.Date)=1) OR ([dbo].[EventSlots].day_monday = 1 AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY, AllDays.Date)=2) OR ([dbo].[EventSlots].day_tuesday = 1 AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY, AllDays.Date)=3) OR ([dbo].[EventSlots].day_wednesday = 1 AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY, AllDays.Date)=4) OR ([dbo].[EventSlots].day_thursday = 1 AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY, AllDays.Date)=5) OR ([dbo].[EventSlots].day_friday = 1 AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY, AllDays.Date)=6) OR ([dbo].[EventSlots].day_saturday = 1 AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY, AllDays.Date)=7) OR ([dbo].[EventSlots].day_sunday=0 AND [dbo].[EventSlots].day_monday=0 AND [dbo].[EventSlots].day_tuesday=0 AND [dbo].[EventSlots].day_wednesday=0 AND [dbo].[EventSlots].day_thursday=0 AND [dbo].[EventSlots].day_friday=0 AND [dbo].[EventSlots].day_saturday=0))
        AND (([dbo].[EventSlots].week_month IS NOT NULL AND [dbo].[EventSlots].week_month=dbo.MONTHWEEK(AllDays.Date)) OR [dbo].[EventSlots].week_month IS NULL) 
        AND (([dbo].[EventSlots].day_of_month IS NOT NULL AND [dbo].[EventSlots].day_of_month=DATEPART(DAY, AllDays.Date)) OR [dbo].[EventSlots].day_of_month IS NULL)
        AND (([dbo].[EventSlots].month_of_year IS NOT NULL AND [dbo].[EventSlots].month_of_year=DATEPART(MONTH, AllDays.Date)) OR [dbo].[EventSlots].month_of_year IS NULL)
    )
    OR ([dbo].[EventSlots].one_time_event=1 AND [dbo].[EventSlots].start_date=AllDays.Date)
        EXCEPT
    SELECT Date
      ,[parent_event_id] "event_id"
      FROM AllDays
      INNER JOIN [dbo].[EventSlots] 
        ON 
        ([dbo].[EventSlots].one_time_event=0 
            AND [dbo].[EventSlots].start_date<=AllDays.Date AND [dbo].[EventSlots].end_date>=AllDays.Date
            AND ( ([dbo].[EventSlots].day_sunday=1 and DATEPART(WEEKDAY, AllDays.Date)=1) OR ([dbo].[EventSlots].day_monday = 1 AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY, AllDays.Date)=2) OR ([dbo].[EventSlots].day_tuesday = 1 AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY, AllDays.Date)=3) OR ([dbo].[EventSlots].day_wednesday = 1 AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY, AllDays.Date)=4) OR ([dbo].[EventSlots].day_thursday = 1 AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY, AllDays.Date)=5) OR ([dbo].[EventSlots].day_friday = 1 AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY, AllDays.Date)=6) OR ([dbo].[EventSlots].day_saturday = 1 AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY, AllDays.Date)=7) OR ([dbo].[EventSlots].day_sunday=0 AND [dbo].[EventSlots].day_monday=0 AND [dbo].[EventSlots].day_tuesday=0 AND [dbo].[EventSlots].day_wednesday=0 AND [dbo].[EventSlots].day_thursday=0 AND [dbo].[EventSlots].day_friday=0 AND [dbo].[EventSlots].day_saturday=0))
            AND (([dbo].[EventSlots].week_month IS NOT NULL AND [dbo].[EventSlots].week_month=dbo.MONTHWEEK(AllDays.Date)) OR [dbo].[EventSlots].week_month IS NULL) 
            AND (([dbo].[EventSlots].day_of_month IS NOT NULL AND [dbo].[EventSlots].day_of_month=DATEPART(DAY, AllDays.Date)) OR [dbo].[EventSlots].day_of_month IS NULL)
            AND (([dbo].[EventSlots].month_of_year IS NOT NULL AND [dbo].[EventSlots].month_of_year=DATEPART(MONTH, AllDays.Date)) OR [dbo].[EventSlots].month_of_year IS NULL)
        )
        OR ([dbo].[EventSlots].one_time_event=1 AND [dbo].[EventSlots].start_date=AllDays.Date)
      WHERE dbo.EventSlots.parent_event_id IS NOT NULL
) AS "FULL"
INNER JOIN dbo.EventSlots ON "FULL".event_id = dbo.EventSlots.event_id
```

The parent_event_id basically are exceptions to your main event. using `MINUS` we can take out those which are replaced by the exceptions!

How does the recurrence pattern work? First we check the date generated from the CTE if it matches any of the weekdays, then the week number in a month , the day of the month and then month of the year. I've also kept a condition where if the values are null it goes to the next one!

I know the code is messy, but it seems to work fine for my use case and I am getting the list correctly!